# Flutter build appbundle after executing flutter clean

Tags: flutter, android-app-bundle

i'm tryind to post my app on playstore but after executing flutter clean, flutter build app bundle dont work again

[image]

Comment: if you are using flutter v3 upgrade your packages

Comment: The flutter clean caused a flutter pub get and it retrieved newer packages than you used previously. Have you upgraded your project to null safety?

Comment: no i'm not on null safety

Answer (score 0):

Execute flutter pub get for update your libraries